# How is a diode packaged

Tags: diodes, fabrication

I need to know the process for packaging a diode such as inserting the die on the package or case, what is that process like.

Comment: Any particular diode? There are many different packaging processes from the vacuum tube diode days onwards.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ;) And I particularly like to get my 1N4004's mounted on an octal base and encapsulated in evacuated glass for my bridge rectifiers, in keeping with those days. Reminiscent, but at the same time modern!